# HttpClient in ASP.NET Core razor async stuck

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I have a problem using ASP.NET Core with app hosted in IIS (not in IIS Express)...

This is my configuration:

Startup:

```
services.addHttpClient()
```

Page:

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

public testModel(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
    _clientFactory = clientFactory;
}

public async void OnGet()
{
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:37199/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // GET Method  
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apiprueba/test");
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);            
}
```

The problem: when I execute the page, I never get a response of the page (test). It only happens with IIS - not with IIS Express. What could be the problem?

**Update:**
New test..no response using simple asp core console.
Code

```
static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:88/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            //GET Method  
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "api/mensaje");
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        }
```

What it means:
Result:
local maquine:
error is shown after 5 seconds..
Server:
Hello world!
_
...code still running after 10 minutes..no answer error or finish the process..

it seems the server is the problem...not sure why

[image]

Update: after reviewed the server ..WinHttp services was stopped...was getting error if I tried to start manually..restarting the server resolved the problem..services start normal and request from app was correct..

Comment: Could you provide the controller and full page code? It's not clear what your expected result is, and when you say it only happens with IIS and not IIS Express what do you mean? What happens?

Comment: is your api (ie: `http://localhost:37199/`) accessible from browser?

Comment: *never get a response of the page* - this is an abstract description. It must return a response either succeeded or failed in an error. You should add logging to log out all the errors to see what's wrong in production (as I understand you deploy your code to `IIS` Server).

Comment: Add some logging to get where it's being stuck. Or capture a trace with PerfView. Or capture a memory dump and analyze it (DebugDiag.Analysis). Or use dotnet-stacks to see where it is hanging.

Comment: "just hangs" sometimes means a thread is deadlocked. Try adding [ConfigureAwait(false)](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f) to your SendAsync

Comment: Hi Nikki..I tried..no changes..  picture is attached now..as you can seee..no error or response..it seems only pause

Comment: add a try/catch around `SendAsync` and set a breakpoint in the catch block and wait 120 seconds after starting a new debug session.

Comment: Use kestrel instead for development and use reverse proxy on production

Comment: Yes...tried..no worked.. actually..firefox on IE was not unable to get pages inside server..that was a clue for server problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinHttp services was stopped..unable to run manually.. after restarting the server the services start correctly and all programs and test was successfull.